# Is there no way to upload hidden files to the web version of iCloud Drive?

Tags: icloud

I have a file I want to manually store in iCloud Drive from my Linux machine. It's a "dotfile" or hidden file (file name beginning with a period).

When I log in to the web version of iCloud Drive and try to upload the file, I see the message:

> There was a problem uploading ".yourfile"
>
> Invalid filename.

Is there no way to upload hidden files to the web version of iCloud Drive? I can zip the file and upload but that adds extra steps to keeping it synced up.

Comment: One wonders if you can take the dot off the file, upload it and *then* rename it back to original? Yah, a PITA but perhaps worth a try?